# Sort an array in descending order for a chart.js bar chart in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to sort the data for a bar chart in chart.js. I am completely new to javascript / typescript and already tried function.sort() but unfortunately it did not work. Does anyone know how to do that?

I basically want to sort the labels descending according to the associated values.

E.g.:

labels: [C,D,A,B]

data1: [10,5,3,1]

```
          const labels: string[] = [];
          const data1: string[] = [];

          if (this.reportData && this.reportData['objects']) {
            this.reportData['objects'].forEach(obj => {
              labels.push(obj.name);
              let count = 0;
              if (obj.scans) {
                count = obj.scans.length;
              }
              data1.push(count as any);
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. First we create a new array in which the elements are objects that combine the label and data for each value. Then we sort that array by the data, and finally we construct the separate arrays again:

```
const labels: string[] = ['C','D','A','B'];
const data1: number[] = [10, 5, 3, 1];

// Construct and array of objects that have 'label' and 'data'
// We expect that labels and data1 are the same length but if there is
// a chance that they are not, you should check for that.
const allData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
    allData.push({
        label: labels[i],
        data: data1[i]
    });
}

// Sort them by the data value
allData.sort((a, b) => a.data - b.data);

// And split them again
const sortedLabels = allData.map(e => e.label);
const sortedData = allData.map(e => e.data);

console.log(sortedLabels);   // ["B", "A", "D", "C"] 
console.log(sortedData);     // [1, 3, 5, 10]
```